# Creating a marhsalled object in C# run time

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have a class:

```
public class NormalClass
{
    public float FloatValue1 {get;set;}
    public float FloatValue2 {get;set;}
    public Boolean BoolValue1 {get;set;}
    public Boolean BoolValue2 {get;set;}
    public TimeSpan milliseconds1 {get;set;}
    public TimeSpan milliseconds2 {get;set;}
    public String StringValue {get;set;}
}
```

In addition to creating an instance of this class. I need to create another instance of the marhalled version of this class.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
public class MarshalledClass
{
    public float FloatValue1;
    public float FloatValue2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public Boolean BoolValue1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public Boolean BoolValue2;
    public int milliseconds1;
    public int milliseconds2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public String StringValue;
}
```

Of cource I dont want too create two definitions of the same class where one is normal and the other one is marshalled. 
Instead i would like to create the normal class, and then marshall a new object in run time. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a problem deleting `NormalClass` and renaming `MarshalledClass` to `NormalClass`?

Comment: In runtime i need an instance of both classes... But i only want to create one class file in C#. Then generate the to instances based on that file. One normal instance, and one instance which is marshalled.

Comment: Out of interest - why are you doing this?

Comment: @MikeD I am communicating with a system which need the object to be marshalled this way. According to doc: To be able to read or write PLC structures the memory layout of the structure or class in .NET must be the same as in the PLC. The layout of a structure or class can be specified with the attribute StructLayoutAttribute. The LayoutKind must be set to LayoutKind.Sequential and the pack must be set to 1. https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_adssamples_net/html/twincat.ads.sample07.htm&id=24212738215243213498